# Java is there any IDE/Tool that can pull SQL statements out in to a file?

Tags: java, sql, external

Hi is there any tool available in Java world that will parse/read a source file and pull SQL statements out in to a text file. This is a complex task given that you can write SQL statements in different fashion within the source (ex: using `+` sign or using `.append()`) or even conditional building of SQL.

Comment: I doubt if there is a common real-world need for it hence a utility readily available.

Comment: I agree, but is there something that will provide a partial solution? For example, I am looking at some legacy code with SQL statements written with in the code. I want an easy way to pull everything out to a properties file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've been considering doing this.  This requires:

1) A full Java parser

2) Full control and data flow analysis, so that you can
track how values propagate through the code

3) Recognition of SQL (JDBC) calls, tracking data flows for the
SQL query back to their origins, and symbolically intrepreting the
set of operations along the data flow paths to determine
the apparant SQL operation.

The [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a generic engine for parsing langauges.  DMS has a full Java front end (meets condition 1) that computes local control and global data data flow analysis (condition 2).   DMS is configurable to extract code properties, so it could be configured we think to do 3.   Still not a trivial task.

But alas, the requested tool is not available yet.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I've ever come across. The few times that people have had to do something like this, they have ended up writing a program to do it, because it's not really something you can generalise.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered having the SQL for the prepared statements in a property file (or language resource bundle) and read them from there?

Comment: Hi - yes, and that is what I was trying to achieve.
Please go through the question again(Guess it is clear enough) - I am looking for a tool that will pull out (externalize) SQLs from java source code that was written by someone a few years ago.

Comment: Your best bet is a package that will allow internationalization of existing code, to extract all strings and label them.  I have no personal experience with such a tool

Answer (score 0):

Check www.antlr.org, they have grammars for PL/SQL, MySQL and Java 1.6. If you only interested in SQL, probably SQL grammar could be something you can build upon.
There could be easier ways about it thought, like reading pseudo SQL from JDBC driver log/wire/from database server log will produce more consistent syntax.